# Reference index of array with number containing variable

Tags: javascript

If I can use array[i] inside of a for loop, why can't I use a different number-containing variable in a similar fashion, for example:

```
var arrayLength = array.length;  
var end = string.slice(array[arrayLength],stringLength);
        console.log(arrayLength);
        theRestArray.push(end);
```

Comment: It contains the slice `end`

Comment: Which is what's left over between the last index of the array and the end of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are zero-indexed, i.e, the first element is `array[0]` and the last is `array[arrayLength-1]`. So, use `array[arrayLength-1]` instead of `array[arrayLength]` and it should work.